# Why is faked IMemoryCache returning default value on Get

Tags: c#, .net, fakeiteasy, memorycache

I'm writing a unit test and therefore i need to fake an IMemoryCache.

```
public MyUseCaseTest()
{
  this.myCache = A.Fake<IMyCache>();
}
```

When i run the test and the tested method is called, the memory cache is checked if there is already an entry inside. Right now the `.Get()` for this memory cache is returning a default value, although nothing was added to the cache before.

Can anybody tell me if this is an expected behavior or if i'm doing something wrong. I know i can fake the call for `.Get()` as well, but i'm interested in why there is an object returned.

Current implementation of the cache looks like this.

```
public class MyCache : IMyCache
{
    private readonly ILogger<AppUserCompanyCache> logger;
    private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;

    public MyCache(ILogger<MyCache> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    }

    public MyModel? Get(Guid key)
    {
        try
        {
            this.memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out MyModel myModel);
            return myModel;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.logger.LogError("Failed to get value from cache!");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Set(Guid key, MyModel myModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.Get(key) != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            this.memoryCache.Set(key, myModel, cacheEntryOptions);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.logger.LogError("Failed to set value to cache!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You already get a fake from `A.Fake<IMyCache>` so I don't see why MyCache is relevant, and yes it is default behavior for FakeItEasy to return default value from fake methods. https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/default-fake-behavior/

Comment: It is expected behavior for a faked memorycache to return a value for ```Get()``` any key, even there where no models set before?

Comment: It is how FakeItEasy create fake in general. It cannot magically realize what kind of behaviour it should implement for each specific type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anybody tell me if this is an expected behavior

Yes, it is. That's probably the biggest behavior difference between FakeItEasy and e.g. Moq: while Moq just returns null by default, FakeItEasy returns a [dummy](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dummies/) (this default behavior is described [here](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/default-fake-behavior/#overrideable-members-are-faked)). Most of the time, this is more convenient and makes the test "arrange" phase shorter. In this specific case, it's not what you want, but you can override it:

```cs
A.CallTo(() => this.myCache.Get(A<Guid>._)).Returns(null);
```